# parsing table in perl

Tags: linux, perl

Suppose i have following table in table format( text format, in linux).

```
index   score   rank    mark
0       100     0       4
1       873     23      89
2       500     15      90
3       224     30      115
```

and so on( more rows and column)..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

open ($fh, '<', "data.txt") 
   or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!"; 

while ($line= <$fh>) { 
   chomp $line; 
   @field = split "\t",$line;
   print "field\n";
}

close $fh;
```

what I need is, to delete some instant, and paste in another file, like

- a) delete all instance of rank<= (less than equal) 15 and paste in another file
- b) compare rank & mark , if difference is >10 , then delete and paste in another file.

please help..

thank you

Comment: @SAYANTANCHANDRA  Put the code you tried in the question by editing it.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
open ($fh, '<', "data.txt") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";

while ($line= <$fh>)
{
 chomp $line; 
 @field = split "\t",$line;
 print "field\n";
}

Comment: Are you allowed to use modules? Text::CSV will get rid of much of the formatting junk.

Comment: Tip: You should ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: You should provide a sample of _output files_ based on _input data_ -- to demonstrate desired result.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- it will assist you to get desired help.

Comment: its better if i do not use modules. Sorry this is my first time here. please pardon for informal way of asking question. Im new in perl

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but some annotations, which do not fit into a comment.

- Use `strict` and `warnings`, if you start learning Perl.
- Declare variables with `my`.
- Don't declare variables, you do not need (`$line`).
- In Perl you can declare variables in list form.
- If you do not `chomp` the input you can output it unmodified.
- Splitting with a regular expression is more robust, than relying on a tab.

Example:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  if (/^index/) { print; next; }
  my ($index, $score, $rank, $mark) = split /\s+/;
  print unless int($rank) < 15;
}
__DATA__
index   score   rank    mark
0       100     0       4
1       873     23      89
2       500     15      90
3       224     30      115
```

Output:

```
index   score   rank    mark
1       873     23      89
2       500     15      90
3       224     30      115
```

The `DATA` change is just for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Keep your file handling.

Comment: `my ($index, $score, $rank, $mark) = split;`

Comment: `print unless $rank < 15;`

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding some abstractions:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie; # Will crash the program if open, close, or print fails.

sub read_line {
  my ($fh) = @_;
  chomp(my $line = <$fh>);
  return undef unless defined $line;
  return split " ", $line;
}

sub write_line {
  my ($fh, @fields) = @_;
  say $fh join("\t", @fields);
}
```

Now you can open the various files for reading/writing and copy the header into output files:

```
open(my $input, "<", "data.txt");
open(my $default_out, ">", "data_new.txt");
open(my $low_rank, ">", "lowrank.txt");
open(my $large_diff, ">", "large_diff.txt");

my @header = read_line($input);
write_line($default_out, @header);
write_line($low_rank, @header);
write_line($large_diff, @header);
```

The main loop is now just a matter of reading lines (making sure to stop if `read_line` returns undef) and following the rules:

```
while (defined(my @fields = read_line($input))) {
    my ($index, $score, $rank, $mark) = @fields;
    if ($rank <= 15) {
        write_line($low_rank, @fields);
    } elsif (...) { # fill in the condition for large_diff yourself
        write_line($large_diff, @fields);
    } else {
        write_line($default_out, @fields);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand overall this code. but can you explain little bit elaborately? please . also say $fh join("\t", @fields); this line is creating problem ( I think module problem )

Comment: You need to `use feature qw(say) ` or `use v5.x` where x is at least 10. Which bit of the code is unclear to you?